# AWS Elastic Beanstalk NGINX configuration not working

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been through the AWS docs and pretty much every stackoverflow answer on this topic and they all pretty much say the same thing. To configure NGINX for a Java Elastic Beanstalk app you create a folder called `.platform` in the root of your repository that looks like this:

```
.platform/
--| nginx/
----| conf.d/
------ my_custom_config.conf
```

And Elastic Beanstalk will put those files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d`.

However, I'm trying this and it's not doing anything. I just see `00_application.conf` and `healthd.conf` in that folder.

I've also tried using `.ebextensions` as opposed to `.platform` even though I knew that wouldn't work because I'm running Amazon Linux 2.

I tried making it look like this as well:

```
.platform/
--| nginx/
----| conf.d/
------| elasticbeanstalk
-------- my_custom_config.conf
```

This didn't work either.

It occured to me that I was specifying my JAR file in `build/libs` as opposed to having the JAR file build to the root of my repo, so I tried copying the JAR file to the root and changing the `.elasticbeanstalk/config.yml` to point there instead, but this also did nothing.

At this point I'm out of ideas.

Platform is Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.2.6.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately this just goes to show that sometimes you need to step away from the computer to actually figure something out.

In my CI, when I originally switched to using `.platform` from `.ebextensions`, I forgot to change that reference everywhere in the script. I was passing `.ebextensions` to `zip` even though the folder didn't exist, as opposed to `.platform`.

Comment: You save my day, same problem :)